# Finding the values of $A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,J$

Tags: number-theory, inequality

Given that the letters $A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,J$ represents a distinct number from $1$ to $9$ each and

$$\frac{A}{J}\left((B+C)^{D-E} - F^{GH}\right) = 10$$
$$C = B + 1$$
$$H = G + 3$$

find (edit: without a calculator) $A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,J$

I could only deduce that $D\ge E$, from the first one. Eliminating C and H doesn't seem to help much either.

Comment: How do you find that $J|A$ couldn't it be either factor is $J$?
I've been looking at this problem and am pretty interested by how to get any progress on it.

Comment: Woops, you are right! I've been looking at it for 4 years now, after my middle school teacher posted it in class.

Comment: Oh wow. I can't get any significant headway(I can reduce it to two cases depending on which one $J$ factors and another two for which is divisible by 5 and the other must be divisible by 2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I would find the solution with no computer aid:

You can write the equation as: $$(B+C)^{D-E} - F^{GH} = 10\frac{J}{A} $$
You can see that the RHS can take very small values ($\le90$). So, I would start with the assumption that it is unlikely to have two very large powers that have difference $\leq$90.

Having this in mind, take a look at the second power ($F^{GH}$) and specifically at the exponent, which equals $GH=G(G+3)$. Its value could be: 4 or 10 or 18 etc. If we had a base bigger than 2, then this makes even the $3^{10}$ a very large number, which is unlikely to solve our problem based on our assumption for large numbers. So exponents $\ge10$ should be avoided, **unless** the base equals 1. (Note that $2^{10}$ is not considered a big number, but we cannot use the number 2 twice for letters F and G, i.e. $2^{2*5}$.

This leaves us with 2 possible solutions:

1. F=1
2. G=1, H=4

In any case, number $1$ has already been used. This means that:

a) Regarding the other power: $(B+C)^{D-E}$,the base can be 5,7,9,11,13,15,17.

b) The right hand side can take values up to 45.

Let's examine the first case (F=1). This means that the first power can take a value up to 46. In how many ways can this be achieved (Remember that number 1 has already been used and that the base can take a value of 5,7,9,...). At first glance, we cannot afford an exponent greater than 2. So let our exponent be 2. Out of the possible bases, only 5 gives us a result less than 46. But we cannot use it because if we use 5=2+3 as en exponent then RHS cannot be greater than 18 (=10/5*9). So **if F=1 then D-E=1**.

Let's examine tha second case (G=1, H=4). Numbers B and C must be consecutive. This leaves us the following possibilities for B+C: 5,11,13,15,17. One of these numbers raised to the X, should be around $Y^4$. And $Y^4 \leq 9^4=6561$:

$5^{5,6,7,8,9}\leq 6561$, leaves us with 5^5=25

$11^{2,3,7,8,9}\leq 6561$, leaves us with 11^2=121 and 11^3=1331

$13^{2,3,5,8,9}\leq 6561$, leaves us with 13^2=169 and 13^3=2197

$15^{2,3,5,6,9}\leq 6561$, leaves us with 15^2=225 and 15^3=3375

$17^{2,3,5,6,7}\leq 6561$, leaves us with 17^2=289 and 17^3=4913

and the possible values for $Y^4$ are 16, 81, 256, 625, 1296, 2401, 4096, 6561

The only pairs with difference less than 45 are: (25-16), (121-81), (289-256) and (1331-1296). This means 9, 40, 33 and 35 respectively. Out of these four, only two can be written in a form compatible with RHS: 121-81=40=10/2*8 and 1331-1296=35=10/2*7.

But the second one has used twice the number 6. So let's examining the first one:

$121-81=10\frac82$ or $(5+6)^2-3^{1\times 4}=10\frac82$ where 2=D-E.

Happily we observe that the two numbers that we haven't already used (7,9) have a difference of 2. So,  $$\frac{2}{8}\left((5+6)^{9-7} - 3^{1\times 4}\right) = 10$$

**Note 1:** I clarify again that this way just finds **a** solution. It could not be used if the problem-maker asked for a proof of a uniqueness of the solution. Moreover, it can surely be computed by hand, as the most "complicated" power was $9^4$.

**Note 2:** This solution is the result of our assumption. We saw that even with small powers, we found only two pairs with small difference. This makes us realize that our initial assumption was legit.

Comment: Is there a more general way to solve equations like this or is it just guessing and seeing where that leads you?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a general way. I'm plannng according to the problem. For example, the first thing i thought about the specific one was that there are some pairs (B,C) (D,E) (G,H) (A,J). Then I tried to exclude some values: A=7,9 and maybe A=3,6,8. But theses wouldn't help much. Then I started thinking like i describe in my solution

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment.

Testing following python code(brute forcing on finite sets is acceptable I think)

```
def funct(t):
    a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j=t
    return (a/j)*(pow(b+c,d-e)-pow(f,g*h))

import itertools
for i in itertools.permutations(range(1,10))
        if funct(i)==10:
              print(i)
```

Total of $64$ possible permutations are returned. I am not sure what the question is asking for. Surely we cannot enumerate *all* of them. Although it is interesting that it is exactly $2^6$. Sample(truncated) output:

[image]

*EDIT*: I just realized that I neglected the other two restrictions. Implementing them to narrow down the search, this is the only possible permutation.

$$(2, 5, 6, 9, 7, 3, 1, 4, 8)$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! It seems that I forgotten to disallow calculators for my question...

Comment: @YiyuanLee No you didn't forget. It is obvious that calculators are not allowed.I did say too long for comment, I don't mean this as an answer, it's just an analysis which I think *might* help.

Comment: Indeed! I could use it to check some of my guesses

Answer (score 1):

We have that $J|A$, and that $\frac{A}{J}|10$. So let's first consider the possible divisors of $10$, which are $1, 2, 5$. Clearly, $\frac{A}{J} \neq 5$ is the most likely option, based on the possible values. So $\frac{A}{J} = 2$. How many ways can we get this? Consider pairs $(A, J)$. We have $(2, 1)$, $(4, 2)$, $(8, 4)$, $(6, 3)$.

We now have that since $\frac{A}{J} = 2$ that $(2B + 1)^{D - E} - F^{G^{2} + 3G} = 5$. I went ahead and substituted based on the constraints given. It will be most helpful to look at how the various digits behave under modular exponentiation, using modulo 10. So for example, when we exponentiate $3$, we get the one's place as $3^{1} \to 3$, $3^{2} \to 9$, $3^{3} \to 7$, $3^{4} \to 1$, $3^{5} \to 3$. The minimum value such that $a^{x} \equiv 1$ $(mod$ $10)$ is called the order of $a$ modulo 10. Once you pick the elements, it comes down to making sure the exponents are in line. Noting the order of an element will help you here.

So how can you make $5$ on the digits places? You have $6 - 1$, $8 - 3$, and $9 - 4$.

I think this should be a sufficient hint to get you going in the right direction.